# AC_CHECK_LIB with multiple dependencies

Tags: autoconf

I want to use the **oqs** library in a project and I have to verify if the library is accesible.
The project uses autoconf and I have to use **AC_CHECK_LIB**.

My first try was:
`AC_CHECK_LIB(oqs, OQS_randombytes, [LIBOQS_LIBS="-loqs"; ac_enable_pqc=yes], [ac_enable_pqc=no])`, but this fails.

I was freaking out, so I've tried to "simulate" what AC_CHECK_LIB does. Created a simple C program which includes the **oqs** library and calls the `OQS_randombytes` function. Compiled it and got a lot of errors. I found out that the **oqs** library have some dependencies and I need to compile it this way:

`gcc test.c -loqs -lssl -lcrypto`.

So there are 2 dependencies. This way I created the following *"thing"* which I don't know if it's correct:

`AC_CHECK_LIB([oqs -lssl -lcrypto], [OQS_randombytes], [LIBOQS_LIBS="-loqs -lssl -lcrypto"; ac_enable_pqc=yes], [ac_enable_pqc=no])`

It really doesn't seems to be ok, but ***IT WORKS***. So, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the last argument from `AC_CHECK_LIB` is for dependencies:

> AC_CHECK_LIB (library, function, [action-if-found], [action-if-not-found], [other-libraries])

In my case:
`AC_CHECK_LIB(oqs, OQS_randombytes, [LIBOQS_LIBS="-loqs"; ac_enable_pqc=yes], [ac_enable_pqc=no], [-lssl -lcrypto])`